# Sftp uploading file's error 0 Byte

Tags: php, sftp

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$filename = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];

require_once('/home/Script_Server/login_server_ftp.php');  

$resConnection = ssh2_connect($strServer, $strServerPort);

if(ssh2_auth_password($resConnection, $strServerUsername, $strServerPassword)){
    //Initialize SFTP subsystem

    echo "connected";
    $resSFTP = ssh2_sftp($resConnection); 
    /*la posizione resSFTP è la / assoluta nel server*/

    $resFile = fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$resSFTP}/". "var/www/html/mysite.com/folder/" . $filename, 'w');

    $srcFile = fopen("/var/www/html/mysite.com/folder/".$filename, 'r');
    $writtenBytes = stream_copy_to_stream($srcFile, $resFile); 
    echo "Byte scritti: " . $writtenBytes;
    fclose($resFile);
    fclose($srcFile);        

}else{
    echo "Unable to authenticate on server";
}



} /*Chiusura POST */
?>
```

Good afternoon , i've a problem with this script called by the form in the html page before this , i catch the file with:  $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"].

This not return error but it upload only the name of file with 0 Bytes size, also the number of writtenBytes is 0 , i'am using CentOs.

Thanks for help .

Comment: `echo "Byte scritti: " . $writtenBytes;` what number does this echo?

Comment: It return number 0   .

Comment: Do you have permissions to write data?

Comment: It's a dedicated server ,  the apache user doesn't already have the permission to his directory(var/www/html/..)??
At the moment i don't  give any permission

Comment: See if the remote server's filesystem is full.

Comment: Absolutly no , the server it's new and it've 2tb of free space

Comment: Can you upload the same file to the SFTP server using any standalone SFTP client from your webserver?

Comment: If you mean this: the upload with winScp (ssh+sftp) work fine , the problem is in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at this a while it's pretty obvious... PHP can't read the file you're asking it to read.  I'm supprised there's no errors in the logs about this, the second `fopen` will fail.

Thats because you're trying to read from the wrong filename

```
"/var/www/html/mysite.com/folder/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]
```

That's not where the file is stored when you upload.  Assuming the field in the form was named `fileToUpload`, the file uploaded by the user will be stored here:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
```

That is you want this line in your code:

```
$srcFile = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'r');
```